# Difference Between Random Variable and Fraction

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\displaystyle \epsilon > 0$ and $\displaystyle X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Prove that, almost surely, there exists only a finite number of rationals $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q}$, with $\displaystyle p\wedge q=1$, such that:

$\displaystyle \left|X-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$

Note: $\displaystyle p\wedge q=1$ means that the greatest common divisor of $p$ and $q$ is $1$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x$ allows inifinitely many approximations $\frac pq$ as in the problem statement, then for each $n$ there exists a $q\ge n$ and a $p$ with $0\le p\le q$ and $p\land q=1$ and $x\in I_{p,q}:=\left]\frac pq-\frac1{q^{2+\epsilon}},\frac pq+\frac1{q^{2+\epsilon}}\right[$. This simply means that $$x\in \bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{q\ge n}\bigcup_{0\le p\le q\atop p\land q=1}I_{p,q}=:C.$$
We compute the measure $\mu(C)$ step by step.
First, we have $$\mu(I_{p,q})=\frac2{q^{2+\epsilon}}.$$
Then for $$A_q:=\bigcup_{0\le p\le q\atop p\wedge q=1} I_{p,q}$$
we have the bound
$$\mu(A_q)\le \phi(q)\cdot \frac2{q^{2+\epsilon}}<\frac 2{q^{1+\epsilon}}.$$
Then
$$ B_n:=\bigcup_{q\ge n}A_q$$
has measure at most
$$\mu(B_n)\le \sum_{q=n}^\infty \frac 2{q^{1+\epsilon}}.$$
Since this series converges (beacuse $\epsilon>0$), we have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n)=0$$
and hence from $C=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty B_k\subseteq B_n$ for all $n$ also
$$\mu(C)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response! Question about notation: what do the outward facing brackets in the second line signify?